# "Solving" a system of linear inequalities for the first variable

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, linear-programming, matrix-equations, operations-research

I have some non-negative real variables $x_1, \ldots ,x_n$ and non-negative real constants $a_{i,j}, 1 \le i \le n, 1 \le j \le n$, such that $a_{i,j} = 0 \iff i > j+1$, and other positive real constants $b_k, 1 \le k \le n$ such that:

$$\begin{align}
a_{1,1}x_1-a_{1,2}x_2+\cdots +(-1)^{1+n}a_{1,n}x_n & \ge b_1 \\
-a_{2,1}x_1+a_{2,2}x_2+\cdots +(-1)^{2+n}a_{2,n}x_n & \ge b_2
\\ & \cdots \\
-a_{n-1,n-2}x_{n-2}+a_{n-1,n-1}x_{n-1}-a_{n-1,n}x_n & \ge b_{n-1} \\
-a_{n,n-1}x_{n-1}+a_{n,n}x_n & \ge b_n
\end{align}  
$$

Each $a_{i,j} \not= 0$ is multiplied by $(-1)^{i+j}$.

I believe that it is always possible to combine the inequalities to get:

$$x_1 \ge A(a_{1,1}, \ldots ,a_{n,n}, b_1, \ldots , b_n)$$

where $A$ is a constant, function of all the $a_{i,j}$ and $b_k$ only. **My goal is getting an analytical formula** for $A$, if actually possible.

I am able to do it for some specific small cases, but I suspect that there might be some well known systematic way of doing it, maybe involving determinants, in a way perhaps similar to solving linear systems of equations.

I read about [Fourier-Motzkin elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier%E2%80%93Motzkin_elimination), however I would like a closed form expression, and I think my case is simpler than the general setup because I have a square $n \times n$ "nearly" triangular matrix made by the $a_{i,j}$ coefficients.

Any hint?

EDIT 2023-01-15:
I have now asked a more precise version of this question at [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/438615/136218).

Answer (score 1):

If you solve a linear programming problem that minimizes $x_1$, yielding an optimal solution with $x_1=A$, the resulting dual variables provide a certificate of optimality.  Explicitly, multiply constraint $i$ by the dual variable $y_i$ and then add everything up to derive valid inequality $x_1 \ge A$.

Comment: Thus if my original problem is $\min \mathbf{c}^\intercal\mathbf{x}$, $\mathbf{Ax}\ge\mathbf{b}$ (here $\mathbf{A}$ is the matrix of the $a_{i,j}$, not the $A$ in the final inequality), $\mathbf{c}^\intercal = (1 \space 0 \ldots 0)$, and the dual problem is $\max \mathbf{b}^\intercal\mathbf{y}, \mathbf{A}^\intercal\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{c}, \mathbf{y} \ge \mathbf{0}$, then $\mathbf{y} = (\mathbf{A}^\intercal)^{-1}\mathbf{c}$ and $x_1 \ge \mathbf{b}^\intercal(\mathbf{A}^\intercal)^{-1}\mathbf{c}$, correct? Also, is verification that $\mathbf{y} \ge \mathbf{0}$ necessary?

Comment: Because $x \ge 0$, the dual constraints are $\le$ rather than $=$.  Also, the nonnegativity of $y$ is a byproduct of solving the primal problem. Most solvers return the duals without you having to explicitly solve the dual problem.

Comment: I was trying to get an analytical formula for $x_1 \ge f(a_{i,j},b_k) = g(n)$ because in my original problem all $a_{i,j}$ and $b_k$ can be expressed as a function of  a single constant value $n$.